# Json Editing mode with ng-prettyjson

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I would like to print json on part of my page. What is more I would like to offer possibility for editing displayed json. I choose [ng-prettyprint](https://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson) for those tasks.

I execute all steps described in [how-to-use-it](https://github.com/darul75/ng-prettyjson#how-to-use-it) section. Unfortunatelly only visualization functionality is working well. On rendered page I do not see button for enabling edit mode, but json is visualized properly.

### My code snippets

Directive usage:

```
<pretty-json json="schema" edition="true"></pretty-json>
```

Inside controller I set value for json:

```
 $scope.schema = {
                   type: "record",
                   name: "test",
                   fields: [{
                      name: "test_field",
                      type: [
                        "double",
                         "null"
                      ]
                 }]};
```

Part of index.html for including ng-prettyjson sources

```
    <head>
    ...
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components//ng-prettyjson/src/ng-prettyjson.css" />
    ...
    </head>
     ...
        <script src="bower_components/ng-prettyjson/src/ace.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ng-prettyjson/src/ng-prettyjson.js"></script>
    ...
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Ok, I Found problem. In latest released version of ng-prettyprint in the definition of the directive code responsible for generating buttons is commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (currently) latest released version(available for `bower`) of `ng-prettyprint`(0.1.3) in the definition of the directive code responsible for generating buttons is commented